# VR slideshow of stereoscopic photos using WebXR

Tags: three.js, aframe, webxr

I have a large and growing library of stereoscopic (not 360) photos in JPS and MPO format which I'd like to share via a website in some form of stereoscopic slideshow for VR headsets.

[A-Frame](https://aframe.io/) looks promising but so far I've found no examples of how to display side-by-side or other stereo image formats.

If I've simply missed such an example, I'd be grateful if someone could point me towards it.

If not, it'd be great to understand how I'd go about creating a slideshow for stereoscopic images using A-Frame or otherwise.

Comment: A gallery like [this](https://aframe-gallery.glitch.me/) ([a-frame has a tutorial on creating it](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/guides/building-a-360-image-gallery.html#sidebar))?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski thanks, I have seen this but it appears to be for 360 panoramic images, not [stereoscopic images such as this](http://www.chasm.com/images/desert.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I've jumped into conclusions way too soon. I don't recall seeing such galleries, but would it be something in [this direction](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-stereoscopic-test?path=index.html%3A4%3A32)(in vr mode on a mobile phone)?

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the kind of thing I'm looking for, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be

- splitting the stereoscopic image into two images, which would correspond to both halves of the original image.
- render each half for its corresponding eye by using the [stereo component](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component)

Which would require two planes:

```
<a-plane material="src: #img; repeat:0.5 1" stereo="eye:left"></a-plane>
<a-plane material="src: #img; repeat:0.5 1; offset: 0.5 0" stereo="eye: right"></a-plane>
```

and setting

- `repeat` to `0.5 1` to render only half the image, and
- offseting the right eye by `0.5 0`

Simple wxample in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-stereoscopic-test) or with a cursor swapping the images in vr mode [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/stereoscopic/index.html)

Comment: I created a [stereoscopic-slideshow](https://github.com/dpa99c/stereoscopic-slideshow) PoC using this approach - you can [view it here](https://dpa99c.github.io/stereoscopic-slideshow/). The only problem I had is the VR browser running out of memory as [outlined here](https://github.com/dpa99c/stereoscopic-slideshow/issues/1) but I will ask about this as a new question